# How to change cPanel theme from xcontroller to x3?

Tags: cpanel, skin

by mistake I changed the cPanel theme to xcontroller and now I can not change back to x3.

I need to know how to change the theme from xcontroller to x3.

I need:

`frontend/xcontroller/index.html`
to
`frontend/x3/index.html`

Comment: What is your cPanel version? Xcontroller was being used in older version. Do you have option "Change style" in your cPanel. Also you can contact your provider to change it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask to your web hosting provider to set it back to x3.